# How to INSERT DATA from table to multiple tables with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatables, sql-insert

I need to insert data from source table to different tables by repsecting number of rows provided in a parameter table and without duplicates.
The same ID's in the parameter table should be inserted in the destination tables for each range of rows.
For example :
FOR ID=1  insert first 200 rows in table_A then insert counting 300 lines  starting from line 201 in source table .

| ID | FILENAME | TOTAL_ROWS | NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT | DESTINATION_TABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FILENAME_X | 500 | 200 | TABLE_A |
| 2 | FILENAME_X | 500 | 300 | TABLE_B |
| 3 | FILENAME_Y | 400 | 100 | TABLE_C |
| 4 | FILENAME_Y | 400 | 300 | TABLE_D |

**Source table**

| s_id | PHONE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| 88 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

**Destination tables**
TABLE A, B, C AND D (with same columns)

| ID | PHONE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXXX | XXXX |
| 2 | XXXX | XXXX |
| 3 | XXXX | XXXX |
| 4 | XXXX | XXXX |

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
       ORDER BY FILENAME) AS RowNum, ID,FILENAME,TOTAL_ROWS,NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT,DESTINATION_TABLE  
FROM [dbo].[parameter_table] ORDER BY FILENAME
OPEN cursor_files
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_files INTO @RowNum,@ID,@FILENAME,@TOTAL_ROWS,NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT,@NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT,@DESTINATION_TABLE

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        IF @NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT > 0
do actions

END
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_files INTO @RowNum,@ID,@FILENAME,@TOTAL_ROWS,NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT,@NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT,@DESTINATION_TABLE

    END

    CLOSE cursor_files
    DEALLOCATE cursor_files
END
```

Comment: can you check destination table values? shouldn't it be ID from the parameter table?

Comment: Also, your source table needs an identity column

Comment: ID's of destination table should be the same as the parameter table as explained.

Comment: I dont need identity column for source table it's a temporary table.

Comment: your source table needs an identity column to be sure about the order. You can't warranty to read the first 100 are first 100 inserted

Comment: OK i added s_id for source table, how can i achieve my goal using a stored procedure please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic query:

```
 declare @strqry as nvarchar(max) = ''   
 
 ;with cte (id,destination_table, end_row) as (
 select id
    ,destination_table
    ,SUM (NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_INSERT) OVER (ORDER BY Id) as end_row  
  from ParameterTable )

  select @strqry = @strqry + 'insert into ' + destination_table + '(ID,Phone,Name) 
    select ' + str(ID) + ', phone, name 
    from SourceTable  
     where s_ID>' + str(isnull(Lag(end_row) OVER(ORDER BY id),0))  +' and s_ID<=' + str(end_row) +';' 

  from cte

   exec sp_executesql @strqry
```

### TEST

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0cea4c/1

[image]